# Avoid iterating too much time - Algorithm construction

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list - `memory_per_instance` -  which looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    'mem_used': '14868480', 
    'rsrc_name': 'node-5b5cf484-g582f'
  },
  {
    'mem_used': '106618880',
    'rsrc_name': 'infrastructure-656cf59bbb-xc6bb'
  },
  {
    'mem_used': '27566080', 
    'rsrc_name': 'infrastructuret-l6fl'
  },
  {  
    'mem_used': '215556096',
    'rsrc_name': 'node-62lnc'
  }
]
```

Now, here we can see that there is 2 resources groups `node` and `infrastructure`.

I would like to create a array of which the final product contains the name of the resource (`node` or `infrastructure`) and the `mem_used` would be the sum of the `mem_used`.

I was already already able to differentiate the two groups from it, with regex.

From now, how can I create an array - `memory_per_group` -  with a result such has

```
[
  {
    'mem_used': '230424576', 
    'rsrc_name': 'node'
  },
  {
    'mem_used': '134184960',
    'rsrc_name': 'infrastructure'
  },
]
```

I could store the name of the `rsrc` in a tmp variable, so something like:

```
memory_per_pod_group = []
for item in memory_per_pod_instance:
    tmp_rsrc = item['rsrc_name']
    if(item['rsrc_name'] == tmp_rsrc):
        memory_per_pod_group.append({'rsrc_name':get_group(tmp_rsrc, pod_hash_map), 'mem_used':mem_used})
        memory_per_pod_instance.remove(item)
pprint.pprint(memory_per_pod_group)
```

But then, I would iterate through the list a non-negligeable amount of time.

Would there be a way to be more efficient ?

Comment: isn't condition `if(item['rsrc_name'] == tmp_rsrc):` always going to be `True` since you are assigning `tmp_rsrc = item['rsrc_name']` just above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sure. You only need one iteration:

```
      data = [
    {
        'mem_used': '14868480', 
        'rsrc_name': 'node-5b5cf484-g582f'
    },
    {
        'mem_used': '106618880',
        'rsrc_name': 'infrastructure-656cf59bbb-xc6bb'
    },
    {
        'mem_used': '27566080',
        'rsrc_name': 'infrastructuret-l6fl'
    },
    {  
        'mem_used': '215556096',
        'rsrc_name': 'node-62lnc'
    }
]

def get_group(item):
    rsrc_name = item['rsrc_name']
    index = rsrc_name.index('-');
    return rsrc_name[0:index]

def summary(list):
    data = {};
    for item in list:
        group = get_group(item)

        if not (group in data):
            data[group] = 0

        data[group] += int(item['mem_used'])

    result = []
    for rsrc_name, mem_used in data.items():
        result.append({ 'rsrc_name': rsrc_name, 'mem_used': str(mem_used) })

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(summary(data))
```

---

**Result:**

```
[{'mem_used': 230424576, 'rsrc_name': 'node'}, {'mem_used': 106618880, 'rsrc_name': 'infrastructure'}, {'mem_used': 27566080, 'rsrc_name': 'infrastructuret'}]
```

Note, that `get_group` might be too simple for your use case. The result has three groups since one of the resources has key `'infrastructuret'` with a "t" at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! :)
The `get_group()` method is already implemented on my side.

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate trough it a single time and checking with a simple [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and then appending directly to the dictionary key that you want with a simple increment.

Something like

```
memory_total = { 'node': 0, 'instance': 0 };

for item in memory_per_instance:
    if item['rsrc_name'].startsWith('node'):
        memory_total['node'] += item['mem_used']
    if item['rsrc_name'].startsWith('infrastructure'):
        memory_total['instance'] += item['mem_used']
```

Comment: That would implies that `node` and `instance` (I guess you meant `infrastructure`) are static. Or they are dynamically discovered.